# getting the contents of a html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

As when i scroll down the mouse  more content are loaded in html page?Is there any way that  i can access all this content without scrolling down the mouse using javascript?

```
var contents  = document.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

this code give div of a html page(without scrolling).

Comment: This simple answer is no. (If I understand your question you are wanting to get content that hasn't even been loaded to the page from the server yet)

Comment: Can i clone the current html web page and use window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);  to scroll the web page such that scrolling is not visible in the browser

Answer (score 1):

You want to access content that is not loaded? You can't...

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHtml`:

```
contents = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
console.log(contents[0].innerHTML);
```

Or if you are using jQuery, add some ID to that div, that you want it's content:

```
<div id='divId'>Hello <span>World</span></div>

$('#divId').text(); // Will return "Hello World"
$('#divId').html(); // Will return "Hello <span>World</span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the content is loaded. If its just invisible, you can get it this way.
But in most cases the content is loaded dynamically, means if the user scrolls to some point, the page sends an ajax request for more content to the server. When the server sends back the data, javascript updates the page. In this case you can't do anything, because it's not possible to send cross-domain ajax-requests.